# How to add inflated view into custom tableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater, android-tablelayout

In the past, whenever I create a custom table layout, I create the children views in java and then add them to the table using `tableRow.addView(childView)`. Presently, instead of creating all my children views by hand, I created them in xml and then inflate them into the tableRow.

So for example I do

```
RelativeLayout gameView = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_game,
            new RelativeLayout(context));
…  //edits to gameView
gameView.requestLayout();
((ViewGroup) gameView.getParent()).removeAllViews();
tableRow.addView(gameView);
addView(tableRow);
```

My problem however is this: If I leave out the line `((ViewGroup) gameView.getParent()).removeAllViews()` then I get an error that the view already has a parent and that I must first call `revomeView` on the child's parent. Not able to find any method called `removeView`, I use `removeAllViews`. But then when I do, I get a NullPointerException on the parent.

So the question: how do I inflate a view and then add it to a table layout?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line

```
RelativeLayout gameView = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_game,
        new RelativeLayout(context));
```

to

```
RelativeLayout gameView = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_game,
        null);
```